# Tic Tac Toe X and Y inversion

Tags: java, applet, coordinates

I am making a tic-tac-toe applet. When I draw the x's, the x and y coordinates are flipped.

```
private byte[][] board = new byte[][] {{0, -1, -1},
                                       {-1, -1, -1},
                                       {0, 0, -1}};
```

where 0's are x's, 1's are o's, and -1's are blank produces on screen

[image: inverted coords]

My code is

```
private int boardSize = getWidth() < getHeight() ? getWidth():getHeight();
@Override
public void paint(Graphics gr) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    boardSize = getWidth() < getHeight() ? getWidth():getHeight();
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(boardSize/72));
    g.drawLine(boardSize/3, 0, boardSize/3, boardSize);
    g.drawLine(2*boardSize/3, 0, 2*boardSize/3, boardSize);

    g.drawLine(0, boardSize/3, boardSize, boardSize/3);
    g.drawLine(0, 2*boardSize/3, boardSize, 2*boardSize/3);

    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(boardSize/144));

    for(byte x = 0; x < 3; x++) for(byte y = 0; y < 3; y++) if(board[x][y] == 0) drawX(g, x, y);
    else if(board[x][y] == 1) drawO(g, x, y);
}

private void drawX(Graphics2D g, byte x, byte y) {
    Stroke s = g.getStroke();

    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(boardSize/72));
    g.drawLine(x*boardSize/3+boardSize/36, y*boardSize/3+boardSize/36, (x+1)*boardSize/3-boardSize/36, (y+1)*boardSize/3-boardSize/36);

    g.setStroke(s);
}
```

`drawO` is not yet implemneted. I don't understand why the coordiantes are flipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `board[x][y]` with `board[y][x]` since the first index represents the blocks  so when `x=0` the vector coming out of the matrix is `{0,-1,-1}`

if you don't want to change `x` with `y`,

you can switch `for` loops

first loop the `y` and then loop the `x`

first solution would look like this:

```
for(byte x = 0; x < 3; x++) for(byte y = 0; y < 3; y++) if(board[y][x] == 0) drawX(g, x, y);
   else if(board[y][x] == 1) drawO(g, x, y);
```

the second solution would look like this

```
for(byte y = 0; y < 3; y++) for(byte x = 0; x < 3; x++) if(board[x][y] == 0) drawX(g, x, y);
    else if(board[x][y] == 1) drawO(g, x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you need to flip `x` and `y`. But I don't feel that they explain why this is the solution very well. Let me show you using some graphics instead.

You know that the coordinate system in Java `Graphics` looks like this:

```
   X
  ------------->
Y |
  |
  |
  v
```

But that is not what your 2D array coordinate system represents. I can tell you wrote the array so as to graphically represent the board, but if you are graphically representing 2D iteration, it works more like `for (each row) for (each column)` than the other way around.

Since you made `y` your inner loop's variable, it became your "column" coordinate, which would normally have been the X coordinate.

```
   y
  ------------->
x | {{0, -1, -1},
  | {-1, -1, -1},
  |  {0,  0, -1}};
  v
```

So you can see why you need to treat your loop variables differently by switching them.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how you define your board

```
private byte[][] board = new byte[][] {{0, -1, -1},
                                   {-1, -1, -1},
                                   {0, 0, -1}};
```

And how you get values out of it

```
board[x][y]
```

When you do `board[x]` you get the `xth` element of board, so if x is 0 then `{0, -1, -1}`, because board is an array of arrays. Then, `board[x][y]` gets the `yth` element of that array, so if y is 1 then the result will be -1.

You should swap how you retrieve elements from board, using `board[y][x]`.